# Regex check to see if any word in string is not longer than limit

Tags: javascript, regex

`Long sentences are long` -- false

`Long words are long` -- true

Check to see if no word in this string is **longer** than 6 characters in a regex.

Most answers I've found online talk about checking the string length or a single word length.

Comment: As any other similar question it must come with a formal definition what a term "word" precisely means.

Comment: You don't need regex for this: `s.split(' ').some((w) => w.length > 6)` where `s` is the string you're testing against.

Comment: The answer marked as duplicate works for [tag:regex] tagged answers, but this can also be accomplished without regex (in javascript alone); unless a [tag:javascript] tagged question exists for the same (and it's added to the list of duplicates for this question), I think this should be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

What Tallboy said, but with a shorter Regex:

```
\S{6,}
```

Test [Here](https://regex101.com/r/vWupQA/1/)

My Regex: 37 steps

Tallboy's Regex: 120 steps

Comment: `\S{6}` <- even shorter

Comment: ya got me there!

Comment: Surprisingly it now reports `40 steps` then 

Comment: I saw that too... weird

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to see if theres any words more than 6 and then reverse it with `!`

```
!/(^| )\w{6,}( |$)/.test("Long sentences are long")

!/(^| )\w{6,}( |$)/.test("Long words are long")
```

Comment: Updated the question. Meant to say to only check if no word is longer than 6 characters.

Comment: @Hellonewman `RegExp.prototype.test`

Comment: @Hellonewman check updated answer

Comment: Actually nevermind this will work just fine. Thanks, trying to improve my regex skills more.

Comment: Sweet  mark dat badboi as the answer fam

Comment: I need to get over 10,000.. im 10 points away O_O

Comment: @Tallboy it looks like you don't need spaces around: just `\w{6}` would do the same.

Comment: Need to wait a minute before accepting